# Continuous image transition like in default iPhone album

Tags: iphone, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I am taking pictures from my custom UIImagePicker camera and saving the images inside the app Document Directory.

Now, when I display the images when a  user Swipes over my image he should see the next/prev image. As of now I have keep the transition discrete(the image doesn't move with the finger; it changes immediately). But I would love the transition be smooth like the one in default iPhone album (smooth and along with the finger).

Can you tell how to achieve this ? 
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to scroll images only than u can used Paging technic:
try this link:

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html
has the proper example too . 
Thanks

Comment: i think if we get any help by someone's effort , we should to appreciate them, and here appreciation means up vote or accept .

Comment: I d love to but as you see, I don't have the reputation enough to Vote  up anyone. Sorry about that for now but when I get the authority I will sure come back and vote you for your answer.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Before and after images:.... this link help u: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work